# Скрипт автозамены значения

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста есть скрипт, через вставку в шаблон не работает, а если вставлять через console в режиме разработчика все работает

```js
function _(selector){return document.querySelector(selector);}
 
_('#mydiv').innerHTML='<span>Номер телефона:</span> '+(_('#cp_id_626').innerHTML.indexOf('Москва')!=-1?'+11111150':'11111111111');
```

Comment: А куда вы его в шаблон вставляете? Страница к тому выполнения уже загрузилась?

Comment: Да вроде. А как сделать, чтобы скрипт грузился когда страница прогружена?

Comment: в функию onload пульни и попробуй

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего скрипт выполняется до того, как страница загрузилась. Можно либо подключать скрипт в самом конце страницы, либо выполнять его при срабатывании эвента `DOMContentLoaded`, например.

```
function _(selector){return document.querySelector(selector);}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  _('#mydiv').innerHTML='<span>Номер телефона:</span> '+(_('#cp_id_626').innerHTML.indexOf('Москва')!=-1?'+11111150':'11111111111');
});
```

Comment: Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Сорри, одна скобка и точка с запятой лишние. Поправил.

Comment: Теперь просто ошибка undefined хотя такой элемент есть

Comment: Все работает, просто вставлял через консоль)

Comment: Вроде работает. http://jsbin.com/subudazoru/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Не до конца работает, теперь выводит вместо всего, вне зависимости от значения города

Comment: Ну тут уже надо смотреть на вёрстку и где какой (и в каком) элемент у вас находится.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46655/discussion-between---and-yuri).

Comment: Не работает только когда вставляешь " .$row['name'] . " вместо города. В бд тоже город храниться